# POSTing to Google Sheets with Perl LWP

Tags: perl, google-sheets

I would like to add worksheets to an existing Google spreadsheet, but am not getting very far. The below does not work for me. Is the below POST request incorrect?

note: My worksheet is indeed public and published on the web. This is confirmed due to the ability to successfully GET request.

[link to Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#add_a_worksheet)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $key = "some key";
my $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/$key/public/full"
my $xml = join "\n", 
    '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"',
            'xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">',
        '<title>Expenses</title>',
        '<gs:rowCount>50</gs:rowCount>',
        '<gs:colCount>10</gs:colCount>',
    '</entry>';

my $response = $agent->post(
    $url, 
    'Content-Type' => 'application/atom+xml', 
    'Content' => $xml
);
$response->is_success && say "OK";
$response->is_error && say "error";
```

Comment: Is that really code you ran? That code fails with a run-time exception because `$agent` isn't defined. You're missing `my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new();` Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! Otherwise, please post the code you actually used, and the result of `$response->as_string`. (Don't forget to obfuscate the key should it appear in the output)

Comment: it's an extract from a lrager body of code. `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` and then a bunch of stuff. hmmm maybe POST is not allowed on a public sheet?

Comment: Do you have a link to the API's documentation?

Comment: Off-topic tip: You can have string literals that span lines, so you could have used `my $xml = ' ... entire XML spread over multiple lines ... ';`

Comment: thank you for the extra tips but I'm really just trying to get the POST request right. I'm just at the testing stage so I won't be using this exact code. rather I am trying to learn how to do it in the abstract so I can apply it later to my real project.

Comment: see edited OP for documentation

Comment: Sorry, I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

From this documentation [link to Google docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#add_a_worksheet)    https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/**private**/full  - is correct url .

Please try change url  from https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/$key/**public**/full to https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/**private**/full